# are you able to position stuff in the bottom in html?

Tags: html

I am using Materialize and I want to position stuff in the bottom with HTML (if that's possible). It sucks when you are trying to navigate through over 2000 lines of code. Can you do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Positioning a nav-bar in the bottom of the page. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <!-- get the required files from 3rd party sources -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="import" href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300italic,500italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="materialize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="materialize.min.css"
  <!-- use the font -->
  <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/hammersmith-one.js"></script>
  <style>
  body .tabs tab-demo z-depth-1 {
    position: static;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
    <body>
      <ul class="tabs tab-demo z-depth-1">
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Test 3</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
              </ul>

              <br>
            </div>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide code? And also elaborate on your question -- what do you mean, "position stuff in the bottom"? The bottom of what? What stuff?

Comment: Positioning a nav-bar on the bottom of the page fixed to the bottom of the page

Comment: "in the bottom in the bottom of the page"? I still don't follow. Do you mean at the end of the page, below everything else, where you have to scroll to it? Or do you mean fixed to the bottom of the screen, and staying there as the user scrolls?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by position:static for some reason, it worked!